# how to remote control Bugzilla (Python preferred)

Tags: python, bugzilla

I'd like to control Bugzilla 2.17.7 from a script to : change comments, key set, create bugz, etc

My tries : 
- Bugzilla tools do not document any example : so I ignore how to do it
- LegNeato : always request remoteobjects for setup
- Pyzilla : from the provided example I have an exception

So: what is the best way to remote control bugzilla with Python ?

PS :Python is preferred because I hardly read Perl but other languages could be ok

Comment: What exception is PyZilla producing?

Answer (score 2):

The [bztools](https://github.com/LegNeato/bztools) module allows you to access the Bugzilla API from Python. Since you are using an old version of Bugzilla, I think you need to patch your installation. From the [Bugzilla API page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3aREST_API):

> If you are on 3.4 or below, you need a patch and a template. These are
>   shipped in the BzAPI distribution, in the patches directory, from
>   version 0.8 onwards. See the INSTALL file for details.

Comment: thx jterrace, nevertheless I'm not alone to use this old BugZilla and therefore the patch is not an option.

Comment: Don't think there is another option.

Comment: i've got bugzilla 3.6 and tried bztools.  however i ran into a couple of problems.  first, i entered my user name and hit enter and then realized i had entered it wrong but couldn't ctrl+c out, so I just hit enter and got a bunch of errors; now when i run again it seems to remember the bad login and I won't prompt me any more so i just get errors again.  Second, I don't see how I am supposed to point it at my bugzilla server, it wants to use bugzilla.mozilla.org apparently, which is not what I need.